# Is ASP.NET DataAnnotations prevent saving passwords as plain-text in memory?

Tags: asp.net, security, memory

Let take part of ASP.NET MVC5 auto-generated code from Visual Studio 2017:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The `password`'s members are tagged with `DataType(DataType.Password)`.
We know that if we hold the password as plain-text, even in RAM at runtime, this is vulnerability.

**My question is if this tag cause the string to store decoded in memory?**

When I'm debugging and look at the memory, I can't find the password, Although that I can find another strings.

Comment: SSL/TLS on the way in as plain text. Hash and salt at rest.